# rtai 4.1 linux kernel 3.10.32 recipe for target 'deb-pkg' failed

Tags: compiler-errors, linux-kernel, patch, rtai

**RTAI4.1 installation for ubuntu 16.04**
when i compile kernel 3.10.32 in my **ubuntu 16.04(x86-64)**
following command which i execute：

```
patch for kernel

cd /usr/src/linux
patch -p1 < /usr/src/rtai/base/arch/x86/patches/hal-linux-3.10.32-x86-5.patch
config

make menuconfig
Set up the kernel settings as follows

Processor type and features
    -> Processor family = Select yours
    -> Maximum number of CPUs (NR_CPUS) = Set your number (it's generally "4")
    -> SMT (Hyperthreading) scheduler support = DISABLE IT
Power Management and ACPI options
    CPU idle PM support = DISABLE IT
build

make -j `getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-rtai
```

when "make -j `getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-rtai " was executed:
**Error**:

> **/scripts/package/Makefile:90: recipe for target 'deb-pkg' failed**
>   make[1]: *** [deb-pkg] Error 1
>
>   Makefile:1078: recipe for target 'deb-pkg' failed
>
>   make: *** [deb-pkg] Error 2

Comment: logs are not very useful, have you tried just 'make deb-pkg' ?

Comment: @Mali apology for reply so late, i changed kernel version and rtai's version that fixed it. So l don't known what really reason to this problem. thank you...

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is from a while ago, but I had a similar problem and I wasn't able to find a fix so I'll post here anyway. It seems that many users have an issue with compiling to a debian package. I'm not sure why this is the case. However, every tutorial I've followed that has had me compile to a debian package has not worked, and every tutorial that has not had me compile to a debian package has worked. Here is one that worked for me. It is specifically for a real time kernel, but the steps are similar. You just need to ignore downloading the realtime patch and you do not need to configure the kernel for real-time. [Install RT Linux patch for Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51669724/install-rt-linux-patch-for-ubuntu)