# Install RT Linux patch for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, real-time, patch, rtos

Trying to make my generic Ubuntu to real time Ubuntu by modifying the kernel by patching / installing RT Linux but couldn't find a straight setup. Can someone help with the steps?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's no straight forward documentation for this, but after some tests I was able to resolve it with the following steps. Pls note that these steps could change depending on when you're reading this, upto date as of 2018-19-20-21.

**Step 0 - Make a working directory**

Make a working directory

```
#Move to working directory
mkdir ~/kernel && cd ~/kernel
```

**Step 1 - Download kernel and patch**

Go to https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/ and download a desired version of kernel to ~/kernel. Similarly, go to https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/ and download the RT patch with same version as the downloaded kernel version. The kernel and patch I used were linux-4.9.115.tar.gz and patch-4.9.155-rt93.patch.gz.

**Step 2 - Unzip the kernel**

```
tar -xzvf linux-4.9.115.tar.gz
```

**Step 3 - Patch the kernel**

```
#Move to kernel source directory
cd linux-4.9.115
gzip -cd ../patch-4.9.115-rt93.patch.gz | patch -p1 --verbose
```

**Step 4 - Enable realtime processing**
This step requires libncurses-dev

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses-dev libssl-dev
```

The next command launches a graphical menu in the terminal to generate the config file.

```
make menuconfig
```

Go to the location and make the changes accordingly

```
##Graphical Menu##

Processor type and features ---> [Enter]
Preemption Model (Voluntary Kernel Preemption (Desktop)) [Enter]
Fully Preemptible Kernel (RT) [Enter] #Select

[Esc][Esc]

Kernel hacking --> [Enter]
Memory Debugging [Enter]
Check for stack overflows #Already deselected - do not select


[Esc][Esc]


[Right Arrow][Right Arrow]

<Save> [Enter]

.config

<Okay> [Enter]

<Exit> [Enter]


[Esc][Esc]


[Right Arrow]
<Exit> [Enter]
```

**Step 5 - Compile the kernel**

```
make -j20
sudo make modules_install -j20
sudo make install -j20
```

**Step 6 - Verify and update**
Verify that initrd.img-4.9.115-rt93, vmlinuz-4.9.115-rt93, and config-4.9.115-rt93 are generated in /boot directory and update the grub.

```
cd /boot
ls
sudo update-grub
```

Verify that there is a menuentry containing the text "menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.9.115-rt93'" in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file

To change default kernel in grub, edit the `GRUB_DEFAULT` value in `/etc/default/grub` to your desired kernel.

**NOTE:** 0 is the 1st menuentry

**7 - Reboot and verify**

```
sudo reboot
```

Once the system reboots, open the terminal and use `uname -a` to check the kernel version, it should look like the following

```
Linux abhay-home 4.9.115-rt93 #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Mon May 13 03:32:57 EDT 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Note:** "SMP PREEMPT RT" validates that your system is running real time kernel.

Comment: I did everything mentioned, changed the default grub to 6, but after booting up uname -a returns old kernel,

Comment: The value 6 might be wrong in the list of menu entries, however you can install the latest kernel version, linux by default picks up the latest kernel version. If your default kernel is 4.15.0 then download kernel 4.16.0 in step 1. If you want the same version then an unconventional way would be to go in the /boot/grub/grub.cfg and find the menu entry for your RT kernel, cut and paste it before the first menuentry. This is not advisable and can mess up with grub boot loader if not done carefully but I've tried this and it works. Hope this helps! Cheers :)

Comment: One can also build debian packages with `make -j<#cores> deb-pkg` and then install them with `sudo dpkg -i linux-*.deb`. This is nice if you want to apply the kernel to several systems.

Comment: Hi Guys, i'm getting error when i execute ( sudo make modules_install -j20  ) it says arch/x86/Makefile:148 CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutilils support. ! that variable is at line 683: in my .conf file . i tried disabling by changing =N and =n still enabled !!!  should i use m ? how can i get through.! any help please .. Also what is the difference between  apt get install linux-rt (https://howtoinstall.co/en/linux-rt) and these list of steps. ? i'm ok to apply rt patch on existing kernel.

Answer (score 10):

Here’s for Ubuntu 19.10 and above and I patched Linux 5.4.5 rt kernel patch because Linux 5.3 -- the base of Ubuntu 19.10 -- has no rt kernel patch.

**0. Make a working directory**

```
# Make dir and move to working directory
$ mkdir ~/kernel && cd ~/kernel
```

**1. Download kernel and patch**

Download kernel and rt patch from https://www.kernel.org/.
You can get these below:

(kernel) https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/
(rt patch) https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/

Note that the version of rt patch and kernel should be same. I used *linux-5.4.5.tar.gz* and *patch-5.4.5-rt3.patch.gz*.

If you download these on the ~/kernel, skip below and move on to step 2.

```
# Move these zip file to ~/kernel
$ cd ~/Download
$ mv linux-5.4.5.tar.gz patch-5.4.5-rt3.patch.gz ~/kernel/.
```

**2. Extract kernel sources and patch rt kernel**

```
# Extract kernel sources
$ cd ~/kernel
$ tar xvzf linux-5.4.5.tar.gz

# Patch rt kernel
$ cd linux-5.4.5
$ gzip -cd ../patch-5.4.5-rt3.patch.gz | patch -p1 --verbose {}
```

**3. Install required packages**

For using menuconfig GUI, `libncurses-dev` is required. `flex` and `bison` will be needed when you compile the kernel.

```
# For using gui
$ sudo apt install libncurses-dev libssl-dev

# For compiling kernel
$ sudo apt install flex bison
```

**4. Configure kernel for RT**

```
$ make menuconfig
```

and enter the menuconfig GUI.

```
# Make preemptible kernel setup
General setup ---> [Enter]
Preemption Model (Voluntary Kernel Preemption (Desktop)) [Enter]
Fully Preemptible Kernel (RT) [Enter] #Select

# Select <SAVE> and <EXIT>
# Check .config file is made properly
```

Note that there’s no `Check for stack overflows` option on GUI configuration anymore. You can check it by searching “overflow”. Type <kbd>/</kbd> and `overflow` on Graphical Menu.

**5. Compile the kernel**

```
$ make -j20
$ sudo make modules_install -j20
$ sudo make install -j20
```

**6. Make kernel images lighter**

As @mrRo8o7 said earlier, big `initrd` image can occur kernel panic. So you can resolve this problem by:

```
# Strip unneeded symbols of object files
$ cd /lib/modules/5.4.5-rt3  # or your new kernel
$ sudo find . -name *.ko -exec strip --strip-unneeded {} +

# Change the compression format
$ sudo vi /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf
# Modify COMPRESS=lz4 to COMPRESS=xz (line 53)

COMPRESS=xz 

[:wq]
```

then update initramfs

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -u
```

**7. Verify and update grub**

Verify that  directory and update the grub.

```
# Make sure that initrd.img-5.4.5-rt3, vmlinuz-5.4.5-rt3, and config-5.4.5-rt3 are generated in /boot
$ cd /boot
$ ls

# Update grub
$ sudo update-grub
```

**8. Reboot and verify**

```
$ sudo reboot

# After the reboot
$ uname -a
```

then you can check your new kernel version

```
Linux [PROMPT] 5.4.5-rt3 …
```

Comment: Following these exact instructions with those file versions, I get a lot of patch failures- "patching file {} ... 4 out of 4 hunks FAILED - saving rejects to file {}.rej  Hmm...The next patch would create the file {}, which already exists! Assume  -R? [n]  Apply anyway?  [n]" - is that normal?  What to answer?

Comment: It seems to work correctly if the "{}" after "--verbose" in step 2 is omitted.

Answer (score 4):

After installing the new kernel (like @Abhay Nayak posted), I got into a kernel panic.
The problem was that the initrd image was too big.
I solved that with:

**Step 1 - Strip the kernel modules**

```bash
cd /lib/modules/<new_kernel>
find . -name *.ko -exec strip --strip-unneeded {} +
```

**Step 2 - Change the initramfs compression**

Edit file /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf:

```bash
COMPRESS=xz
```

**Step 3 - Update initramfs**

```bash
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo update-grub2
```

Answer (score 2):

The `PREEMPT_RT` patch has slowly been streamed to the **Linux mainline** and **from Ubuntu 22.04 onward** it can be activated with a few simple commands as described [here](https://ubuntu.com/blog/real-time-ubuntu-released).

---

For prior versions of Ubuntu note that you can also download **Debian packages for certain `PREEMPT_RT` kernels** from the official [Debian packages web page](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=linux-image-rt-amd64). If you do not care about the precise kernel version I would prefer that over re-compiling the kernel yourself!
After downloading the Debian file you can install it from the download directory with

```
$ sudo dpkg -i linux-image-rt-amd64_5.10.106-1_amd64.deb
$ sudo apt-get install -f
```

where `linux-image-rt-amd64_5.10.106-1_amd64.deb` clearly depends on the version that you downloaded. Reboot into the freshly installed kernel (verify that the current kernel name indeed contains `rt` with `$ uname -r`) and you should be ready to go!

---

In case you really want/have to **compile the kernel** you might have to **set the following kernel flags** in the `.config` after `$ make oldconfig` (or `$ make menuconfig`)

```
CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS=""
CONFIG_SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS=""
```

else the compilation process might fail with a cryptic error message following the steps given by the other commentators.

I have recently written a more detailed **guide** on the required steps [here](https://github.com/2b-t/docker-realtime/blob/master/doc/realtime_basics/PreemptRt.md). In the process I have also written **two scripts** that allow you to install it from existing Debian packages or compile the kernel yourself with a graphic user interface. Have a look at the [**Github** repository](https://github.com/2b-t/docker-realtime) for this.

Answer (score 0):

## 1 Create working directory

```
mkdir ~/kernel && cd ~/kernel
```

## 2 Download kernel source files and real-time patch files

```
wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/linux-5.4.209.tar.gz 
wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/5.4/patch-5.4.209-rt77.patch.xz
```

## 3 Unpack source files

```
tar -xzf linux-5.4.209.tar.gz&
xz -d patch-5.4.209-rt77.patch.xz
# wait until tar -xzf linux-5.4.209.tar.gz job finish
cd linux-5.4.209
patch -p1 <../patch-5.4.209-rt77.patch
```

## 4 Configure build options

```
cp /boot/config-5.15.0-43-generic .config
# install dependency
sudo apt update
sudo apt install make gcc libncurses-dev libssl-dev flex libelf-dev bison
# install menu GUI to set configuration option "The RT option"
make menuconfig

# In Graphic menu to set up as follows:
# General setup  —>
# Preemption Model (Voluntary Kernel Preemption (Desktop))  —>
# ( ) Fully Preemptible Kernel (Real-Time) # select
# then SAVE and EXIT

# disable some options to update config file
scripts/config --disable SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS --disable SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS --disable CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF
```

## 5 Build the kernel

```
sudo make 
# do a check as follows, there should not be any error then we succeed to build. 
sudo make -s >/dev/null
```

## 6 Install the kernel modules

```
sudo make modules_install install
```

## 7 Configure bootloader option

```
sudo vim /etc/default/grub
# to set GRUB_TIMEOUT=-1
# which means it will stop until you choose specific kernel when boot.
```

## 8 Reboot and verify

```
reboot
# choose your real-time kernel, like 5.4.209-rt77
# After you log in,
# print out your real-time kernel name
uname -r
# show scheduler options, it should differ from the generic-linux-kernel's.
cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
```