# How to enable CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED in Ubuntu to make it RT

Tags: linux, ubuntu, real-time, cgroups

I need to run real time applications on Ubuntu RT Linux and was reading about ways to make linux act as RT system and I learned two ways to do it

1. preemptive_rt kernel patching
2. enabling `CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED` flag in the kernel.

I've already tried my hands on 1st method [Install RT Linux patch for Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51669724/install-rt-linux-patch-for-ubuntu)

However, apart from `uname -r` showing `#1 SMP PREEMPT RT` I've no other proof that it is actually a RT system and hence want to try the 2nd method. Enable `CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED` flag in the kernel and see its performance.

I read we can confirm if the kernel already has the flag by following command:

```
# zcat /proc/config.gz | grep RT_GROUP

CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED=y
```

However, my system doesn't even have the config.gz file in proc, so I believe my kernel does not have this enabled.
I'm relatively new to linux kernels so this might be naive but how can I enable this in the kernel?

Answer (score 5):

**Step 1**
Download linux kernel from https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/. For the purpose of this PoC we downloaded `linux-4.16.18.tar.gz` kernel from above link.

**Step 2**
Unzip the kernel

```sh
$ tar -xzvf linux-4.16.18.tar.gz
```

**Step 3**

Move to kernel source directory

```sh
$ cd linux-4.16.18
```

**Step 4**

Install kernel build dependencies

```sh
$ sudo apt install git build-essential kernel-package fakeroot libncurses5-dev libssl-dev ccache bison flex
```

**Step 5**

Run kernel configuration

```sh
$make menuconfig
```

**Step 6**

Go to `General setup` ─> `Control Group Support` ─> `CPU controller` ─> `Group scheduling for SCHED_RR/FIFO` configuration as shown below:

[image]

Go to `General setup` ─> `Kernel .config support` and enable access to `.config` through `/proc/config.gz`

**Step 7**

Compile the kernel

```sh
$ make -j20
```

Make modules & install

```sh
$ sudo make modules_install -j20
$ sudo make install -j20
```

**Step 8**

Open the `grub.cfg` file to verify if kernel is installed

```sh
$ vim /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Look for the menuentry with `menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux linux-4.16.18'`

If it's not your default kernel then change the `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` value to your kernel

**Step 9**

Reboot your system

`sudo reboot`

**Step 10**

Verify the system by the following command:

```
# zcat /proc/config.gz | grep RT_GROUP

CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED=y
```