# Changing thread real time scheduling policy fails: CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED=y

Tags: c++, docker, linux-kernel, real-time, cgroups

My apologies if I'm posting this here instead of super user.

I was trying to run docker inside real-time group and I came across enabling cgroups - `CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED` in the kernel to run real-time docker applications (here: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#configure-the-default-cfs-scheduler)

I configured my kernel to enable the FIFO/RR flags and verified it (Available here: [How to enable CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED in Ubuntu to make it RT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56189710/how-to-enable-config-rt-group-sched-in-ubuntu-to-make-it-rt))

I believe my system is properly scheduled now because I'm able to run the resource limited docker on this system which accesses the cgroups with the following command:

```
$ docker run -it --cpu-rt-runtime=950000 \
                      --ulimit rtprio=99 \
                      --cap-add=sys_nice \
                      debian:jessie
```

I went ahead and tried to explore more features of RT system. I've this CPP code to assign RT priority scheduling to threads. This code basically tries to set the `SCHED_FIFO` priority to a thread and prints if the kernel allowed it to set the priority or not.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sched.h>

using namespace std;

void set_realtime_priority() {
     int ret;
     // We'll operate on the currently running thread.
     pthread_t this_thread = pthread_self();
     // struct sched_param is used to store the scheduling priority
     struct sched_param params;

     // We'll set the priority to the maximum.
     params.sched_priority = sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_FIFO);
     std::cout << "Trying to set thread realtime prio = " << params.sched_priority << std::endl;

     // Attempt to set thread real-time priority to the SCHED_FIFO policy
     ret = pthread_setschedparam(this_thread, SCHED_FIFO, &params);
     if (ret != 0) {
         // Print the error
         std::cout << "Unsuccessful in setting thread realtime prio" << std::endl;
         return;     
     }
     // Now verify the change in thread priority
     int policy = 0;
     ret = pthread_getschedparam(this_thread, &policy, &params);
     if (ret != 0) {
         std::cout << "Couldn't retrieve real-time scheduling paramers" << std::endl;
         return;
     }

     // Check the correct policy was applied
     if(policy != SCHED_FIFO) {
         std::cout << "Scheduling is NOT SCHED_FIFO!" << std::endl;
     } else {
         std::cout << "SCHED_FIFO OK" << std::endl;
     }

     // Print thread scheduling priority
     std::cout << "Thread priority is " << params.sched_priority << std::endl; 
}

int main(){
set_realtime_priority();
return 0;
}
```

I've verified this code on a generic ubuntu/fedora and RT patched CentOS system. All of these systems allow the code to set the priority. Surprisingly its the `CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED=y` configured kernel which doesn't allow me to set the priority policy. Similarly it also doesn't allow `cyclictest` to run

```
//install cyclictest by following

$ sudo apt-get install rt-tests
$ sudo cyclictest
```

I didn't understand this anomalous behavior. Does enabling the CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED somehow block me from changing scheduling policies?

Comment: What is the value of `errno`? Which call does fail? `doesn't allow cyclictest to run` what do you mean by that?

Comment: @KamilCuk pthread_setschedparam() is unsuccessful because the kernel doesn't allow it to change scheduling policy. Cyclictest is a performance analysis tool which also tries to change the scheduling policy and the system responds with "Unable to change scheduling policy"

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you've got fixed it or not, but I met same problem yesterday and here is a solution of mine.

When CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED=y, you should give a permission to run a(some) RT thread(s) to your cgroup. It can be done by giving proper value to "rt_runtime_us" node.

1) Find a cgroup for cyclictest

It follows the cgroup for shell process if it is lunched by shell command. Please enter below command to find the cgroup for cyclictest or sh process

] ps -O cgroup

2) Allocate proper timeslot for rt schedule to your cgroup

In my case, 'sh' process is into the "system.slice/system-serial-blabla" cgroup.
So, I gave max timeslot to these cgroup hierarchy and it's been fixed.

] echo 950000 > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/system.slice/cpu.rt_runtime_us

] echo 950000 > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/system.slice/system-serial-blabla/cpu.rt_runtime_us

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [Yongho Shin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60665456/9938686) you still have to allocate a proper time slot for the control group where your `cyclictest` is run - irrespectively of whether you are running it from inside the Docker or outside of it - else it will show you the error message `Unable to change scheduling policy! either run as root or join realtime group`. As already pointed out by the error message itself you will have to [run the process in the real-time `cgroup`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60665456) as follows:

First let's install **`cgexec`** from the [`cgroup-tools`](https://github.com/mk-fg/cgroup-tools):

```
$ sudo apt-get install cgroup-tools
```

Then **allocate a time slice for the cgroup** (in the following example `950000`) that your process should run in by modifying the corresponding configuration file, e.g.:

```
$ sudo echo 950000 > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/system.slice/cpu.rt_runtime_us
```

Finally you can then **launch a process inside the `cgroup`** with something like

```
$ sudo cgexec -g subsystems:path_to_cgroup command arguments
```

In the case of our `cyclictest` our command could look like:

```
$ sudo cgexec -g cpu:system.slice cyclictest -m -sp99 -d0
```