# Ubuntu22.04 makes Preempt_RT work but CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED is not set

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, preempt-rt

I followed the instructions on the [official](https://ubuntu.com/blog/real-time-linux-qa) to compile the Linux kernel into a real-time system that can preempt low-priority work.

Due to some factors I need to use "CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED". But when I searched for availability, the following results appeared:
[CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED is not set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gc4QJ.png)

Then I looked for [related messages](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/realtime/documentation/known_limitations) and found that it doesn't seem to be available.
What should I do next? Should I follow [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56189710/how-to-enable-config-rt-group-sched-in-ubuntu-to-make-it-rt) to compile the kernel to an older version? I don't think this is a good way.

This is my kernel version:5.15.0-1028-realtime

Comment: Do you honestly need a picture to represent your kernel version? Please use text that can also be indexed and searched! Also, what precisely do you mean with "when I searched for my availability"? Please, be precise with what you did and what you observed. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Thank you very much for your reminder, I will make corrections and understand immediately!