# Cannot make kernel .config

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, real-time

I'm setting up RTLinux on a Siemens machine. I cannot seem to generate the config file for the kernel.

I have been following this guide: [Install RT Linux patch for Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51669724/install-rt-linux-patch-for-ubuntu) and I get stuck at Step 4

I started by installing ubuntu 16.10. Then I installed the linux kernel (linux-5.2.19.tar.gz) and also the RTLinux patch (patch-5.2.19-rt10.patch.gz). I created a working irectory ~/kernel. I unzipped the kernel into this directory and successfully patched the kernel.

I now need to install ncurses:

`sudo apt-get install libncurses-dev libssl-dev`

When I do this I get a bunch of 404 errors like it cannot reach the archives.

Because of this I went and installed ncurses manually. I went to https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/ncurses/ncurses-6.1.tar.gz, downloaded the tar and performed the following steps.

```
cd ncurses-6.1
./configure --prefix=/opt/ncurses
make
sudo make install
ls -la /opt/ncurses
```

The final line verified the install was correct.

Now I navigate back to my ~/kernel/linux-5.2.19 directory and perform a `make menuconfig`
and receive the following errors:

```
*
* Unable to find the ncurses package.
* Install ncurses (ncurses-devel or libncurses-dev
* depending on your distribution).
*
scripts/kconfig/Makefile:206: recipe for target 'scripts/kconfig/mconf-cfg' failed
make[1]: *** [scripts/kconfig/mconf-cfg] Error 1
Makefile:559: recipe for target 'menuconfig' failed
make: *** [menuconfig] Error 2
```

I appreciate any responses/advice.

Comment: Don't follow random internet tutorials.  Follow the directions in the kernel source.  Start with file README in the root directory

Comment: Evidently Ubuntu 16.10 is EOL. I will be reinstalling a different version and will update.